# Do Google Calendar events have option to redirect participant to external URL as meeting is ended?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-meet

Does google calendar events have option to redirect participant to external URL as meeting is ended?

Zoom has a "post-attendee URL" with this functionality. We are looking to redirect our Google Meet participants to a feedback page on our website.

If there are any parameters for the API call that we can utilize to do this, please let us know what they are.

Comment: If something is not supported in the web application it will not be supported in the API.

Answer (score 1):

In the current state, as [@Ryan M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208273/ryan-m) pointed, there is no default option such as `post-attendee URL`

You can request this functionality via this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906), to add it to the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option.

You can include a link to the feedback page in the description, but there is no option to automatically redirect users to it after a meeting.